# How do you force UTF-8 encoding for Win RT WebView

Tags: c#, utf-8, webview, character-encoding, windows-runtime

I'm writing a universal app for Windows 8.1 / Windows Phone 8.1 that displays web pages in a `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView`.
The pages are encoded in UTF-8 but they are being displayed as 8-bit text.

Is there a way to force the `Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView` to interpret the page as UTF-8?

I am loading the pages using `NavigateToLocalStreamUri` so there are no HTTP headers involved.

If I load the page in Internet Explorer on the desktop then it also treats it as 8-bit text and forcing the encoding using the view menu causes the page to display correctly.

The page itself starts

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

so I don't know why IE gets it wrong at all

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>` does not look like HTML... Are you sure you are posted correct text here?

Answer (score 2):

You could try specifying the encoding in a `meta` tag in the `head` of the page:

For HTML 4:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

For HTML 5:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```